# PHP DOM document generating malformed XML feed

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to create a feed for Google Merchant using php and DOM document.

The feed contains thousands of items, yet fails to validate because there are a tiny handful of cases(4/5 out of 6000+) where the XML is malformed, for example:

```
 <g:product_type>Plantsg:product_type>
```

I am generating  in a foreach loop

```
    //Loop through each plant
    foreach($plantList as $plantItem){

        //begin item element
        $item = $xml->createElement('item');


        //Loop through use key as element name and value as data
        foreach ($plantItem as $key => $value)
        {
            //Decode HTML characters, for example '&' becomes  &amp
            //to comply with http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_12
            $decode = htmlspecialchars_decode($value);
            $decode = trim($decode);

            if(empty($decode))
              continue;

            //Create the element
            $tag = $xml->createElement($key);
            $tag = $item->appendChild($tag);

            //Write the field
            $text = $xml->createTextNode($decode);
            $text = $tag->appendChild($text);

        }
        $item = $channel->appendChild($item);
    }
```

**[Here is the xml entire generation code.](https://gist.github.com/4620003)**

Here are the 3 malformed tags:

```
g:adwords_grouping>18</g:adwords_grouping>

form>10 ltr pot</form>

title>Buy Helleborus x nigercors</title>
```

The malformed tags pop up in different places when I make adjusments to the code. Usually its either missing '

Comment: Could you show us the 4/5 cases that are malformed?

Comment: Hmm, tough one. Could you provide more context, i.e. the output around the malformed tags?

Comment: All I see is a blank canvas. Please check again.

Comment: Have you tried to save the output of `$xml->saveXML()` to a file and see whether it contains the malformed tags? I'm pretty sure that PHP's DOM extension isn't the cause.

Comment: are you using multitasking?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted again at : notepad.cc/xmlfeed

Comment: No multitasking, were using Zend framework, the code is executed inside a controller.

Comment: Also the same happens when saving to a file via $xml->save('filename')

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode` looks misused. Also which component is producing this invalid XML. Is that your own code or is that from an external system?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all those who tried to solve it. The malformed tags were put there by Chrome when it encounters an encoding problem.

See [image: annotated screenshot] . In this case it opened the ,  tag encountered 'ö', then fell over and didn't close the  tag.

I am also incorrectly using htmlspecialchars_decode when I should be using just htmlspecialchars as pointed out by hakre, but thats a whole different problem.

Comment: if your problem is effectively resolved, it would be best to accept your answer as the solution, otherwise your question sits in the "unanswered" list forever.

Answer (score 0):

I am with @aefxx it would be helpful if you can provide a few lines right before and after the line where you see the malformed opening tag (looks like all examples you showed are missing just one character in opening tag).